# Possibility of caching ls-remote calls

Tags: git, jenkins

I am looking for a possibility to cache `git ls-remote <url>` calls. Context: We have about 25 parallel Jenkins jobs which do each 400 ls-remotes simultaniously leading to a slow git/gitlab. All 25 jobs do requests on the same repositories, but resulting in different results in the end. I know, this sounds like a design failure, but it's necessary - unfortunately.

So yeah, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on those jobs to do the ls-remote, you could:

- have a dedicated job doing only the minimum required ls-remote calls, each one modifying a file if there is any change
- have your 25 parallel jobs triggered by a change to their respective files.

That is: use files as "flag" to trigger a job, instead of embedded ls-remote calls in those jobs.

---

The [OP Kevin Kendzia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5313200/kevin-kendzia) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634873/possibility-of-caching-ls-remote-calls/43644003#comment74505181_43644003):

> We fixed it now by modifying the build system - we doing it once now and writing the hash into a specific file.
>   Like you suggested with a dedicated job before.

Comment: Ok, we fixed it now by modifying the build system - we doing it once now and writing the hash into a specific file. Like you suggested with a dedicated job before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KevinKendzia Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.